Difference between smooth and continuous $\ell$-adic representations
I am studying the book "The local Langlands conjecture for GL$_2$" scribed by Bushnell and Henniart. When they talk about $\ell$-adic representations, they assert without explanation that smooth representations of a locally profinite group $G$ are continuous. But I don't find it so obvious.
The definitions that I have are

A representation $\rho: G \to Aut_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_{\ell}}V$ is smooth if the stabilizer of $v$ is open in $G$ for any vector $v$ in $V$.


A representation $\rho: G \to Aut_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_{\ell}}V$ is continuous if $\rho$ is continuous with respect the topology induced by the isomorphism $Aut_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_{\ell}}V \cong GL_d(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_{\ell})$ where $d$ is the dimension of $V$.

The idea that I have is to work with the associated action
$$G \times V \to V$$
but it is not to easy to justify the fact that the book doesn't prove it, so I think that I am not noticing something really easy.

Try to think “smooth” as “locally constant”.

@coLaideronnette : Clearly since $G$ is locally profinite and the stabilizer of $v$ is open, any vector $v$ is stabilized by an open compact subgroup of $G$. But after that?

How would you define the topology in use on $GL_d$?

@WillSawin : It is the product topology $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_l ^{d\times d}$

The topology on $GL_d$ is generated by open sets of the form $V= \{ g \mid  e_i \cdot g e_j \in U \} $ for $U$ an open subset of $\overline{\mathbb Q}_\ell$.
For any $g$ with $\rho(g) \in V$, the stabilizer $S$ of $\rho(g) e_j$ is open by assumption. So $S g$ is open since $G$ is a topological group. But $\rho(Sg)\subset V$ since for $h \in S g$, $\rho(h )e_j \in \rho(S g )e_j=\rho(S) \rho(g)e_j$ so $\rho(h) e_j = \rho(g) e_j$. So $Sg \subset \rho^{-1}(V)$. Hence $\rho^{-1}(V)$ is open.
